# How to set data into data table on click function?

Tags: javascript, angular

When we fetch data dynamically from API then data table search not work, when we enter any string into data table input search it is clear the table and after remove the string from search text table not show any data but when we try it without fetching data from API then it is work properly.

it is my html file code

```
 <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let data of TableData;let i = index;">
        <td>{{data.TXN_ID}}</td>
        <td>{{data.CREATE_DATE}}</td>
        <td>{{data.OID}}</td>
        <td>{{data.OID}}</td>
        <td>{{data.businessName}}</td>
        <td>{{data.CUST_EMAIL}}</td>
        <td>{{data.PAYMENT_TYPE}}</td>
        <td>{{data.CURRENCY_CODE}}</td>
        <td>{{data.AMOUNT}}</td>
        <td>{{data.INTERNAL_CURRENCY_CHANGE_RATE}}</td>
        <td>{{data.TXN_ID}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

it is my ts file code

```
    ngAfterViewInit(){

        this.dataTable = $(this.dataTable.nativeElement);
        this.dtOptions = {
          dom: "<'dt-toolbar'<'col-xs-12 col-sm-6'f><'col-sm-6 col-xs-12 hidden-xs text-right'" +
          "B" +
          ">r>" +
          "t" +
          "<'dt-toolbar-footer'<'col-sm-6 col-xs-12 hidden-xs' l><'col-xs-12 col-sm-6'p>>",
          orderCellsTop: true,
          fixedHeader: {
            header: true,
            footer: true
          },
          deferRender:true,
          autoWidth: true,
          retrieve: false,
          responsive: false,
          scrollX:false,
          buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print',
            {
              extend: 'collection',
              text: 'Select Columns',
              buttons: [ {
                extend: 'columnsToggle',
                columns: ':not([data-visible="false"])'
              } ],
              className: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm m-5 width-140 assets-select-btn toolbox-delete-selected'
            },
          ],
        };
        let _dataTable = this.dataTable.DataTable(this.dtOptions);

        // $('#dataTable thead tr').clone(true).appendTo('#dataTable thead');

        $('#dataTable thead tr:eq(1) th').each( function (i) {
          var title = $(this).text();
          $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );

          $('input', this).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            if ( _dataTable.column(i).search() !== this.value ) {
              _dataTable
              .column(i)
              .search( this.value )
              .draw();
            }
          } );
        } );



     this.getDataFromService.getReport(body).subscribe(data => {
      this.TableData = data['statusDesc'];
    });
}
```

Comment: After u update data in table again render it

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Kindly ensure and verify that you hand out all the relevant information which are required for your question. E.g. the code you have posted does not contain any logic regarding a search function at all.

Comment: @Çağrı we get the data from api ,but when i seach data then it is not work ,but when we not get data from api then it is work properly

Comment: @mamichels it is working  properly when we did not get data from api .when we set static data it work very well

Comment: what do you mean by static data , an array declared in your ts file ?

Comment: Yes right because your table at first is nothing then u added bu u didn't rendered table with new datas coming from api,

Comment: @AymenTAGHLISSIA yes

Comment: After u get data from api and set it to your model render your table again

Comment: @Çağrı  yes, it render the data but when we start search then it is clear tha table

Comment: can u create a stackblitz example? what is table library?

Comment: Now i am trying to resolve the issue , i realize , it is not work when we call the data after render the data data table, but if we call the api from ngOnInIt then it work